# Final touchups to a word doc

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a completed PhD thesis in word and I need to finalize it.  I don't want a minor edit (like a change to a page #) to throw all the other pages off -  I want to freely edit the word doc.

Is there a way to turn it into a "touch" up doc, so I can finalize my changes?

Comment: Do you mean make changes, but not have anything change pages, or something else entirely?

Comment: Typically people do not worry about that stuff unless they quoted page numbers within their document. If you used MSWord's Table of Contents then you can just right click on it and update the table. If you are referencing page numbers in your thesis, then you may be screwed.

Comment: i mean, i want to add final touchups to a word doc that aren't supported by ms word.  how can i do this ?  One solution - export it as a series of jpegs... but that seems like overkill.

Comment: JPG is a terrible choice of format...

Answer (score 1):

If all of your tables and references are inserted as fields (EG the table of contents and tables of figures) then no matter what changes you make, an update will resolve any references so long as the fields are unlocked (the default).

Comment: so is there a way to convert a word file to something raw, editable, simple ?